# What are the possible types of folder descriptions

Tags: java, swing, filesystems

Using [`FileSystemView.getSystemTypeDescription(File f)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemTypeDescription-java.io.File-) what are the possible return values when it returns a `String`.

Some examples might be `CD Drive`, `Local Drive` and `Network Drive`, however, I cannot find any documentation that lists all possible values for this method.

*Note*
Looking in the source files I found `getShellFolder(f).getFolderType()` within [`FileSystemView.getSystemTypeDescription(File f)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemTypeDescription-java.io.File-). I believe this method uses this [sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/awt/shell/ShellFolder.java#ShellFolder.getFolderType%28%29)
, however, I had no luck finding possible values.

Answer (score 1):

You linked to the documentation in your question.  It does not define a constrained set of possible values.  It says that the values will be system-dependent (which could include the OS, version, locale, desktop customizations, etc.).  So the answer is that it can basically be anything, but it will be recognizable to users of the system (assuming they actually know their own system).

Comment: So how would I find the values for operating systems such windows 7, 8, and 10

Comment: Run the code and try it.  Document the version of the JRE on which you tried it, since the API documentation doesn't prevent the results from being different on different JREs.

Comment: Is there a way to get the values from an internal file on a PC instead of testing different devices. For example, I had a network drive and when it was disconnected it showed up as a disconnected network drive. If I hadn't accidently done that I wouldn't have thought it might be a result. This is why the question asks if there is a way to list all the results

Comment: Again, the API does not define what you seek.  It is implementation dependent.  So it will depend on a particular implementation.  Perhaps we have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here?